# Datatables: Upload - Display Thumbnail of PDF

Tags: pdf, datatables, thumbnails

I'm using the standard upload function in Datatables. Images correctly display thumbnails. How do I get a PDF that's uploaded to display a thumbnail? Currently it just displays a small broken file icon.

From the HTML:

```
{ "className": "dt-right", data: "image",
            render: function ( file_id ) {
                return file_id ?
                    '<img src="'+editor.file( 'files', file_id ).web_path+'" class="img-circle" width="40" height="40"/>' :
                    null;
            },
            defaultContent: "No image",
            title: "image"
        }
```

From the PHP:

```
Field::inst( 'image' )
->setFormatter( 'Format::ifEmpty', null )
->upload( Upload::inst( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/__ID__.__EXTN__' )
    ->db( 'files', 'id', array(
        'filename'    => Upload::DB_FILE_NAME,
        'filesize'    => Upload::DB_FILE_SIZE,
        'web_path'    => Upload::DB_WEB_PATH,
        'system_path' => Upload::DB_SYSTEM_PATH
    ) )
    ->validator( function ( $file ) {
        return$file['size'] >= 2000000 ?
            "Files must be smaller than 2M" :
            null;
    } )
    ->allowedExtensions( array( 'png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'pdf' ), "Please upload an image" )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a thumbnail service like [Post2Preview](https://post2preview.com), it supports hundreds of file types. Disclaimer: I work for Post2Preview